# Explanations on software requirements terms needed

Tags: analysis

Have several questions. Don't flame me - I'm newbie, but eager to know more. So:

1. What is the difference between Software requirement specification (SRS) and Functional requirement specification (FRS)? Maybe, anybody can provide with links of both so that I could see the difference?
2. What is system interactive architecture map (IA map)? Can anybody provide with a link so I could see a real sample?
3. Also, what is modular breakup?

Thank you very much.
Donny

Comment: This is awesome, I'm taking it to my next game of Buzzword Bingo!
In all seriousness, large organizations use phrases like this somewhat interchangably and the meaning is not always precise. Where I work, we have High Level Designs, Detailed Designs, Functional Specs, System Architecture Documents,... Talk to whoever sent you that list of terms and ask them for a definition, because they're definition will probably have subtle (and probably arbitrary) differences from ours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen documentation split between "Functional Requirements" and "Technical Requirements". In that situation, the **functional requirements document is written in non-technical language** that non-technical readers on the user side can understand. It avoids terminology that only an IT person would use.

"Requirements" often include not only what the software is supposed to do, but other topics such as performance criteria (response time, number of concurrent users), security, programming language, browser or O/S to be supported, and the database to be used. **One of the key parts of the requirements document is the definition of what is and is not in scope.** And who the stakeholders and decision-makers are.

Answer (score 3):

The *requirements* indicate what a piece of software is supposed to do.

*Functional requirements* say what the software should do. E.g. when you click this button, this dialog should appear.

*Non-functional requirements* have to do with the quality of the software. It should feel snappy, it should display the window within 0.1 sec, it should be possible to deploy it to multiple servers, etc.